# How to combine few .grd files and store them in network independent netcdf format used for?

Tags: c++, grid, gis, netcdf

I am trying to convert the output format of my project on TSUNAMI MODEL visualization. I am doing this to help the local weather forecasting agency. But I've struck on the problem on the output format of the "existing" program.

The program outputs the results in **".grd format"**, but I want them to be in **".netcdf format"**.

Further each of the .grd contains processed images of the input image (which is also in .grd). Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this?

I have referred the official documentation of netCDF on https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/ but I am unable to make any progress for a while now.

The routine that write the data in ".grd format" is the below one

```
int FILEOTPROPA()
{
  FILE *fp;
  short nOutI,nOutJ;
  int i,j,m;
  float ftmp;
  double dtmp,lonOutMin,lonOutMax,latOutMin,latOutMax;
  char record[128];

  CNode& Node = *gNode;

  NrecSpatialWaveOutput++;

  nOutI = Imax-Imin+1;
  lonOutMin = getLon(Imin); lonOutMax = getLon(Imax);
  nOutJ = Jmax-Jmin+1;
  latOutMin = getLat(Jmin); latOutMax = getLat(Jmax);

  sprintf( record, "zout_%5.5d.grd",MODELVARI.time );
 fp = fopen( record, "wb" );
  fwrite( "DSBB", 4, 1, fp );
  fwrite( &nOutI, sizeof(short), 1, fp );
  fwrite( &nOutJ, sizeof(short), 1, fp );
  fwrite( &lonOutMin, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  fwrite( &lonOutMax, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  fwrite( &latOutMin, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  fwrite( &latOutMax, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  dtmp = -1.; fwrite( &dtmp, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  dtmp = +1.; fwrite( &dtmp, sizeof(double), 1, fp );
  for( j=Jmin; j<=Jmax; j++ ) {
    for( i=Imin; i<=Imax; i++ ) {
      m = idx(j,i);
      if( fabs(Node(m, iZ)) < MODELVARI.zoutTT )
        ftmp = (float)9999;
      else
        ftmp = (float)Node(m, iZ);
      fwrite( &ftmp, sizeof(float), 1, fp );
    }
  }
  fclose( fp );
  return 0;
}
```

This routine generates around five ".grd format" picture files during each execution. I want to combine this five ".grd format" picture files in to single netCDF format file as an output for each execution of the program.

Sample execution of the program generated .grd files (in examples folder) and complete source code can be found at https://mega.nz/#F!oqhVVA4a!VPdVav4bQQVsJTuYbMIOFw

Thank you.